# UDP Server Windows Service and dependencies

Tags: .net, windows-services, udp

I'm wondering if/what  windows service dependency I must set up on a .net application that is acting as a Udp-server for remote clients.

Answer (score 0):

At minimum, I recommend placing a dependency on the "Workstation" service (which provides basic network connections and communications). I would also add "Server" (which supports file, print & named pipe sharing) to be safe.

And if you can tolerate a slightly slower start at boot, [set your service to "Automatic (Delayed start)"](https://superuser.com/questions/285653/what-does-delayed-start-do-in-startup-type-for-a-windows-service) to give all the critical services plenty of time to come up before you join the fray...